# is there anyway to undo an activerecord delete in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have made an unbelievably horrible mistake in script/console:

```
user.delete
```

Is there any way to undo that from within the same script/console session?

Comment: If you happened to do something unfortunate like like User.destroy_all and you didn't save a reference to the resulting array AND you're using pry AND you haven't executed any other commands yet, then you might be able to use the special `_` local variable to get the most recent result.

Answer (score 26):

Well, if you remain to have access to the deleted record, you can just create a new replica like this

```
User.new(user.attributes_hash).save
```

That will just create a user with the *exaxt same* attributes (yes, also the id) and save it to the DB. I use this to undo a destroy action using the flash.

**Caveat.** If you have used the `User#destroy` method and your model has relations with `dependent: :destroy` or `dependent: :delete`, then those dependent records – if present when executing the command – will be lost. Unless, of course, you have active references, i.e. variables, to the deleted/destroyed records.

Comment: I've ended up using a variation. Notice this version only works when :id, is in attr_accessible, which is not (at all) best practice.

Comment: It's a long shot but something like this can also work for associations:

Comment: In Rails 5+, it would be `User.new(user.attributes).save`.

Comment: @nurinur Please bear in midn, that my answer was for Rails 2, I think. Back then it was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know of a way either, it might be possible that you still have the information in your shell history. (Just scroll up till you executed `user.delete`). You could manually restore the user instance, which gets tricky if you had dependencies/associations.

For the future: you might want to start the console in sandbox mode via:

```
rails console -s
```

All changes will be rolled back after you close it.

**Edit: Please take a look at [Arne L.'s Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27079964/980524)** it shows a way to save the user to the database if the object is still available. Thats much better than what I proposed ("manually restore the user").

Comment: This is a really nice pointer, but it does not solve the issue _after_ the damage is done. I provided an answer which repairs the damage -- sadly, it's really to late for the OP. ;-)

Comment: @ArneL. Yep! Thanks I edited the answer so people from the future should upvote you :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. Unless you're using a gem like Papertrail that's keeping a history of your changes, the record is gone.

Comment: i still have everything there in user (presumably because i haven't executed a user.reload) just trying to figure out the best course of action... user = user.clone and then save that maybe?

Comment: Oh that makes a huge difference. If you've got it in memory, I'd assume saving it would effectively undo the delete.

Comment: save didn't help, but this seems to have done the trick:

`user2 = user.clone`
`user2.id = user.id`
`user2.save(false)`